# Get All Parents/ Children Of Record In Table

Tags: python, sql, django

I have an SQL (Postgres) table named “Items” with the following schema.

```
id | parent_id | name
```

Where the `parent_id` column is a ForeignKey to the same table. (E.g items have parent items and those items can have parent items)

This makes a simple branching hierarchy.

Currently I query for the specific record and use a `for loop` to get each of its parents/ children. 
This results in numerous queries being executed.

What I’m wanting to do is query this table using the id of one of the items and get all of its parents/ children returned using a single query.

I can accomplish this by using `.select_related(“parent__parent”)` or `.prefetch_related(“item_set”)`for the children, but both of these approaches would require knowing the depth of the hierarchy before hand.

Is there a way in Django to get all of the related rows in a single query? 
Raw SQL is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive solution for getting the parent and children hierarchy  of a record.

```
select * from 
(WITH RECURSIVE cte_items (id, name, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id        
    FROM items
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent_id
    FROM items e
      INNER JOIN cte_items o ON o.id = e.parent_id)
SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM cte_items) child
union
select * from 
(WITH RECURSIVE cte_items (id, name, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id        
    FROM items
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent_id
    FROM items e
      INNER JOIN cte_items o ON o.parent_id = e.id)
SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM cte_items) parent
order by parent_id
```

---

Comment: That’s great but is there a way to run it in the reverse? To get the children and parents or a record?

Comment: I have updated the query, using an UNION between parent and child. Is this what you are looking for ?  Here the updated query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bf6b9/43

Comment: That is an incredible query. thank you so much. ill edit the answer to put the new sql

Answer (score 0):

*OP Note*

I have modified the great code provided by Nicola with the following.

The code is a little clearer and performs marginally fewer actions on the table.

The `where id = 1` in each of the SELECTS is the actual id of the record you are wanting to query for.

```
WITH parents  AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id        
    FROM family
    WHERE id = 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent_id
    FROM family e
    INNER JOIN parents o ON e.id = o.parent_id)
, children  as (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id        
    FROM family
    WHERE id = 1  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.name, e.parent_id
    FROM family e
    INNER JOIN children o ON o.id = e.parent_id 
)
SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM parents
UNION
SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM children;
```